# IP parsing results in an odd value

Tags: parsing, ip-address

On my computer, the following line:

```
System.Net.IPAddress result = default(System.Net.IPAddress);
bool success = System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse("234.34.034.004", out result);
```

creates the following results

1. success evaluates to true
2. The IP Address result returned is 234.34.**28**.4

What is happening?

Comment: 34 in decimal form is 22 in hex, so that doesn't describe what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the "34" is being interpreted as octal because it has a leading zero.  (The 4 probably also is being interpreted as octal, but its representation is the same in both bases).

34 in octal is 28 in decimal, thus the output.

Comment: Quite possibly because [(winsock) `inet_addr` does so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-inet_addr) although `System.Net.IPAddress` doc doesn't say so.